# Visual basic extract folder names and compare them with active directory users

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

im a newbie in vb script writing and I want to extract folder names and compare them with active directory users I started with the following code:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Log file name
Set logFile = fs.OpenTextFile("fileNameLogs.txt", 2, True)
'Directory you want listed
Set folder = fs.GetFolder("\\server\Data\Users")

Set files = folder.files
For Each file in files
    logFile.writeline(file.name)
Next
logFile.close
```

This script only extracts the file names not the folder names.
Can any one help me continue and extract the folder names instead of the file names so I can compare them active directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track just use the `.SubFolders` object collection to iterate through the `Folder` objects in the current `Folder` object similar to the approach you have used for the `File` objects.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fs, logFile
Dim folder, subFolders, subFolder
Dim files, file

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Log file name
Set logFile = fs.OpenTextFile("fileNameLogs.txt", 2, True)
'Directory you want listed
Set folder = fs.GetFolder("\\server\Data\Users")

'Write out sub folders
Set subFolders = folder.SubFolders
For Each subFolder In subFolders
    logFile.Writeline(subFolder.Name)
Next
Set subFolders = Nothing

'Write out files
Set files = folder.files
For Each file In files
    logFile.Writeline(file.Name)
Next
Set files = Nothing
logFile.Close

'Clean-up and reclaim memory
Set logFile = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```